# align textview below ImageView

Tags: android, textview, imageview, alignment

I've one ImageView and 3 TextViews. I need to align the 3 text views below the imageview. the first on the left . the second in center. the 3rd on the right.

below code is working for normal and small screens. but for tablets and large screens, the first text view is not below the imageview. it's shifted too left. and the third TextView is shifted too Right.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Rel_wind2_img">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/window2_image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/window2_image1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/window2_image1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/window2_image1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/window2_image1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/info2_txt_moves"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I can solve this problem grammatically. but i need a simple way using XML.

Comment: If it is creating problems for tablet, create an extra layout for tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Give layout weight inside a linear layout. It will set the width equally between all textviews. try this

```
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Rel_wind2_img"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/window2_image1"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/window2_image1"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="info2_txt_moves"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this One :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Rel_wind2_img"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/window2_image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView
    android:text="dfgf"
    android:id="@+id/TV1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TV2"
    android:text="dfgf"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TV3"
    android:text="dfgf"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: I tried it, it's a little bit better than my code, but TV1 & TV3 still shifted far from the image view.

Comment: Did you mean tv1 and tv3 both are below in image view like tv2?

Comment: I need to put tv1 below the image ( aligned below the image in the left). tv3 same in the right. I have no problem in tv2, as it's always in center.

Comment: TV1 still shifted left, not sharply below the image , same tv3 still shifted to right

Comment: can you send screen short.what to u want exactly?

Comment: it's Ok now. Just adding weightsum to the second layout and it's 100% working fine. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this kind of UI design just divide the Layout into weights.
because if we divide the ui in weights it will automatically adjust according to divide size so there will be no problem on any device. 
like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Rel_wind2_img">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tr"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/window2_image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/tr"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dhshshs"
            />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="fjkhajhjfha"
            />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV3"
            android:text="aoifoijoajoifjoajofjafafg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/window2_image1"

      />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```